# Why unsigned xcarchive is larger than signed?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcodebuild

I use the following command to generate **signed** xcarchive:

```
xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme app -configuration 'Release' -sdk iphoneos archive -archivePath build/signed.xcarchive
```

to build **unsigned** xcarchive I just append at the end:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

And I'm curious why unsigned xcarchive has 332 MB and signed 222 MB?

I found out that for example `libswiftCore.dylib` in signed xcarchive has only 23.3 MB and in unsigned has 95.4 MB. Strange.

- Xcode 10.2.1
- Swift 4
- Deployment target: 10.0
- Using `CocoaPods`
- Additional dependencies: `Alamofire`

[image: Difference]

Comment: I wonder if it stripped out different architectures. I can't reproduce your issue but my guess would be that architectures are missing in the signed version of libswiftCore.dylib. Do you mind posting the output of `otool -L [PATH TO libswiftCore.dylib]`

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess output for signed and unsigned libswiftCore.dylib is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation by comparing output of each build using `opendiff` I discovered that for signed build `xcodebuild` runs `bitcode_strip` on each `dylib` which significantly reduces size.

That's why there is the difference in size between those two builds.

To be more specific in case of unsigned build `xcodebuild` runs:

> builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose ...

and without parameter `--sign` it doesn't strip bitcode. Message from build output:

> Ignoring --strip-bitcode because --sign was not passed

Therefore it seems to be an intended behaviour of `xcodebuild`.